# Having trouble with an if statement. (New programmer.)

Tags: c++

```
    correct = 0;
    cout << "You entered " << years << ".\nIs that correct? (Y/N) \n";
    cin >> yesNo;
    if (yesNo == 'y' || 'Y')
         correct ++;
} while (correct != 1);
    cout << "good! " << correct << endl;
return 0;
```

}
I want it to only ++ the correct int if yesNo = y or Y, if it doesn't, I want it to loop back up to the top (unseen)

Comment: Try not to guess the syntax, you can and will get results you won't expect. Like `'Y'` evaluating to `true`, so you're whole condition is always true? You might want to read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You should turn on your compiler warnings, i'm sure it'll cringe at `(yesNo == 'y' || 'Y')`.

Comment: While you're at it. Make `correct` a `bool`.

Comment: I changed correct to bool, and I also changed the if statement to include yesNo on both parts of or.

Comment: Also I'm going to check out one of those books at least. Right now I'm using fundamentals of c++ by Tony Gaddis.
Can I upvote comments? RickAstley helped out and I wanted to give him some rep or something positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess  your problem is in

```
if (yesNo == 'y' || 'Y')
```

It should be

```
if (yesNo == 'y' || yesNo== 'Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fixed my problem!

Answer (score 3):

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bf3edba51feec45

Your problem is the `if (yesNo == 'y' || 'Y')`. What this if-statement says, is

> If `yesNo` is equal to `'y'` or `'Y'` is `true`, proceed.

The thing is, `'Y'` is always true, because the `char` is implicitly converted into a `bool`.

What you probably meant, is `if (yesNo == 'y' || yesNo == 'Y')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the above answer, but I just wanted to let you know that I appreciate the information you gave in addition to the answer.